# jQuery remove() from div doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to remove a div in jQuery. This is my code but I have test and doesn't work, the div  doesn't remove. help me.

```
var img_old=$(".colCenter").find('#div_'+old_id);
img_old.delay(10).animate({top:1440},1500, function(){
img_old.remove();
});
```

This is the html

```
<div class="colCenter" id="two">
    <div id="randomdiv" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="content" id="div_index">
        <div class="img_background">
                        <img src="img/sfondi/index.jpg" alt="" class="old_img" id="img_index"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo_home">
                        <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo_grande.png" alt="Web & Design" title="Web & Design" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So does `img_old` actually have a reference to an element?

Comment: Can you post your HTML please.

Comment: And a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FJchB/ -- your code works fine for me. Either your HTML isn't constructed the way you expect, or the variable `old_id` isn't set.

Comment: There is no `colCenter` class in your posted HTML.

Comment: There is no element with class of colCenter in your markup.

Comment: What's the value of `old_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FJchB/ -- your code works fine for me.

Perhaps the variable `old_id` isn't set in your code? I had to set it to "index" to get anything to happen.

As others have suggested, you also need to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready{...}` block so it only runs after the elements are loaded.

Comment: is set beacuse is a dynamic page

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
 var img_old=$(".colCenter").find('#divx');
 img_old.delay(10).animate({top:1440},1500, function(){
 img_old.remove();
});
});
</script>
<div class="colCenter">
<div  id="divx">Another one text 3</div> 
</div>
```

Works fine for me.
Try to execute javascript code where DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `old_id` is "index", otherwise your code doesn't work. Because there is only div_index.

Try to do this code between:

```
$('document').ready( function() {
```

and

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in this example here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWDp3/)

**HTML**

```
ID: <input type="text" id="id" value="0"/>

<div>
   <div class="colCenter">
      <div id="div_0">0</div>
      <div id="div_1">1</div>
      <div id="div_2">2</div>
      <div id="div_3">3</div>
   </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Go"/>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {

        var old_id = $('#id').val();
        var img_old = $(".colCenter").find('#div_' + old_id);
        img_old.delay(10).animate({
            top: 1440
        }, 1500, function() {
            img_old.remove();
        });
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

***try this***

```
var old_id = 'index';
var img_old = $('.colCenter').find('#div_' + old_id);
img_old.delay(10).animate({
    top: 1440
}, 1500, function() {
    img_old.remove();
});
```